How to upper bound $\sum_{m=2}^{d-1}\binom{n}{d+1+m} n^{-\alpha 2m} $
As I'm saying in the title, I am looking for an upper bound (or an identity) for this:
$$
\sum_{m=2}^{d-1}\binom{n}{d+1+m} n^{-\alpha 2m}
$$
where $\alpha \in [0,\infty)$.
Any ideas/suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

By shifting the index of the sum, we get $$\sum_{m=2}^{d-1} {n \choose {d+1+m}} n^{-2\alpha m} = \sum_{m=d+3}^{2d} {n \choose m} n^{-2 \alpha (m-d-1)} = n^{2\alpha (d+1)}\sum_{m=d+3}^{2d} {n \choose m} n^{-2 \alpha m}~.$$
If $d \le 2$ the sum is just $0$. So let $d\ge 3$. A weak upper bound can be obtained by applying the binomial theorem:
$$n^{2\alpha (d+1)}\sum_{m=d+3}^{2d} {n \choose m} n^{-2 \alpha m} \le n^{2\alpha (d+1)}\sum_{m=6}^{\infty} {n \choose m} {(n^{-2\alpha})}^{m} = n^{2\alpha (d+1)} \left(  (1+n^{-2\alpha})^n -\sum_{m=0}^5 {n \choose m}n^{-2\alpha m} \right)~. $$
In total for $d \ge3$ we then have the bound $$\sum_{m=2}^{d-1} {n \choose {d+1+m}} n^{-2\alpha m} \le n^{2\alpha (d+1)} \left(  (1+n^{-2\alpha})^n -\sum_{m=0}^5 {n \choose m}n^{-2\alpha m} \right) \le  n^{2\alpha (d+1)} (1+n^{-2\alpha})^n ~.$$
if $n\ge0$ the problem can be reduced to bounds for the cumulative binomial distribution(because  $p \in [0,1]$ ). By setting $$ p := \frac{1}{1+n^{2\alpha}} \iff n^{-2\alpha} = \frac{p}{1-p}$$ we have $$n^{2\alpha (d+1)}\sum_{m=d+3}^{2d} {n \choose m} n^{-2 \alpha m} = n^{2\alpha (d+1)} (1-p)^{-n} \sum_{m=d+3}^{2d} {n \choose m} \left( \frac{p}{1-p} \right)^m (1-p)^{n} \\ = n^{2\alpha (d+1)} (1-p)^{-n} \sum_{m=d+3}^{2d} {n \choose m} p^m (1-p)^{n-m} $$
Now define $$F(k;n;p) := \sum_{i=0}^k {n \choose i} p^{i} (1-p)^{n-i}~. $$
Then we can express $$n^{2\alpha (d+1)} (1-p)^{-n} \sum_{m=d+3}^{2d} {n \choose m} p^m (1-p)^{n-m} = n^{2\alpha (d+1)} (1-p)^{-n} [F(2d;n;p) -F(d+2;n;p)]$$
Using the defintion of $p$ we obtain $$\sum_{m=2}^{d-1} {n \choose {d+1+m}} n^{-2\alpha m} = n^{2\alpha (d+1)} (1-\frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}+1})^{-n} [F(2d;n;\frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}+1}) -F(d+2;n;\frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}+1})]~.$$
With more information about the size of $d$ and $n$ there are already many estimates for the cumulative binomial distribution function $F$.

Thank you very much!
